# linux send SIGTERM to child cause ssh connection refused

Tags: c, linux, ssh

assume I have a main process (parent) with two children spawned in my embedded linux (child1, child2)

I can also use ssh normally with no problem after boot up

Scenario 1:

1. I connect to my embedded linux via ssh on port 22
2. I run `parent` which executes itself and `child1` and `child2` normally
3. I kill `parent` with `SIGTERM` signal
4. in the `parent` I use `kill(child1_pid, SIGKILL)` and `kill(child2_pid, SIGKILL)`
5. everything is fine :)

Scenario 2:

1. I connect to my embedded linux via ssh on port 22
2. I run `parent` which executes itself and `child1` and `child2` normally
3. I kill `parent` with `SIGTERM` signal
4. in the `parent` I use `kill(child1_pid, SIGTERM)` and `kill(child2_pid, SIGTERM)`
5. ssh session are closed and another retry for reconnecting results into `ssh connection refused` :|

after a reboot ssh turns back and I can use it

absolutely have no idea!

---

Edit 1: here is the code

```
#define safe_free(x) ({free(x); x = NULL;})

pid_t child1_pid;
pid_t child2_pid;

bool file_exists(char* file_name)
{
    if( access(file_name,F_OK) == 0 )
        return true;

    return false;
}

pid_t process_fork_and_exec(char* program_file_path, char* argv[])
{
    if( file_exists(program_file_path) == false )
        return -1;

    pid_t _pid = fork();
    if( _pid == -1 ) {
        return -2;
    } else if( _pid > 0 ) { /* **** parent process **** */
        return _pid;
    } else {  /* **** child process **** */
        // When parent exits, send SIGKILL to all children:
        // if parent is died with SIGKILL, so should do children
        prctl(PR_SET_PDEATHSIG, SIGKILL);
        // executing binary
        execv(program_file_path, argv);
        // nothing is returned here
    }
}


int parent_processes_init()
{
    char* _parent_abs_path = get_parent_path();
    char* _parent_dirname = dirname(_parent_abs_path);
    
    char _child1_file_name[400];
    char _child2_file_name[400];
    // next 2 lines determine path for child1 and child2
    sprintf(_child1_file_name, "%s/child1", _parent_dirname);
    sprintf(_child2_file_name, "%s/child2", _parent_dirname);

    if( file_exists(_child1_file_name) == false ) {
        fprintf("[error] child1 binary file does not exists\n");
        safe_free(_parent_abs_path);
        return -2;
    }
    if( file_exists(_child2_file_name) == false ) {
        fprintf("[error] child2 binary file does not exists\n");
        safe_free(_parent_abs_path);
        return -3;
    }

    // starting child1
    child1_pid = process_fork_and_exec(_child1_file_name, (char*[]){_child1_file_name, NULL});
    if( child1_pid < 0 ) {
        fprintf("[error] warming up child1...failed\n");
        safe_free(_parent_abs_path);
        return -2;
    }
    parent_fprintf("warming up child1...done\n");

    // starting child2
    child2_pid = process_fork_and_exec(_child2_file_name, (char*[]){_child2_file_name, NULL});
    if( child2_pid < 0 ) {
        fprintf("[error] warming up child2...failed\n");
        safe_free(_parent_abs_path);
        return -3;
    }
    parent_fprintf("warming up child2...done\n");

    safe_free(_parent_abs_path);

    return 0;
}


void parent_processes_term()
{
    if( child1_pid != (pid_t)-1 ) {
        kill(child1_pid, SIGKILL);
        // kill(child1_pid, SIGTERM);
        // kill(child1_pid, SIGABRT);
        child1_pid = (pid_t)-1;
    }
    if( child2_pid != (pid_t)-1 ) {
        kill(child2_pid, SIGKILL);
        // kill(child1_pid, SIGTERM);
        // kill(child1_pid, SIGABRT);
        child2_pid = (pid_t)-1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please provide a [minimal verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). That is, show a simplified version of the code that can reproduce the problem.

Comment: @kaylum attached the code

Comment: You should add some debugging so you can see the value of child1_pid right before `kill(child1_pid, SIGKILL);` , if you have a bug somewhere , and child1_pid is 0, that will kill all processes in your process group, or worse if child1_pid is negative, you might kill everything on your machine if your program runs as root

Comment: @nos in `parent_processes_init` I have checked for it; programs will never run if pids of children are < 0

Comment: Yes, but I would still log it so you can be sure that there's not a bug in your program

Comment: @nos yep! you're right

Comment: You could have used [libssh](https://www.libssh.org/) and you should read [*Advanced Linux Programming*](https://mentorembedded.github.io/advancedlinuxprogramming/) and [syscalls(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscalls.2.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

found at last!

I terminate `child1` twice when I uncomment for `SIGTERM`

I think after first `kill`, `child1_pid` gets a negative value, and negative pids in linux point to a group of processes; maybe including `sshd` process :|